# How do I flip a rigged model to its mirror image?

Tags: mesh, armature, mirror

thanks for looking.  I have a mesh with armature, a robotic right hand.  I have the model completed, and now I want to create its mirror image, a robotic left hand.  I can flip the mesh and I can flip the armature, but I can't seem to figure out how to do both at once.  Failing that, can anybody give me some guidance on how to do each individually and then merge the new mesh and new armature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure both the mesh and armature are selected:

1. In *Object Types > Visibility*, make sure both mesh and armature are selected
2. Press <kbd>A</kbd> to select all
3. Right click and select *Mirror > X-Global*